# Windows 11 can't connect to Ubuntu samba shares?

Tags: networking, samba

I have problem to connect from Windows 11 to my sambashares on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTSbut to my sambashare on Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ the connection works.

When I tested with Windows 10 I was able to connect both Ubuntu's and RaspberryPi's samba shares without problems. Raspberry Pi has Samba version 4.13.13-Debian installed and Ubuntu has Samba version 4.18.6 installed.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Check the Authentication types...  Windows always used to be a pain with Samba.  You may need to turn on SMB 1.0/CIFS in Windows Features?